# Python removing ([ from a text file

Tags: python, text-files

So basically in my text file, the information is layed out like this

```
([x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,x],[x,x,x,x],[x,x,x])
```

how would i remove the brackets so that all of it becomes one array and i can just call it by `position[0]` or `position[10]`?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval(open('path/to/file').read())` gives you a tuple with three lists

Comment: And using the output from @inspectorG4dget's code, it would be pretty simple to flatten the tuple.

Comment: `result = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(ast.literal_eval(open('path/to/file').read())))`

Comment: any simplified version for a code like this ` file = open('scores.txt','r')
for line in file:
    position = line.strip('\n').split(",")
print(position[0])`

Comment: Your fundamental problem is you have cooked up your own text-based serialization format. Now you are stuckcoming up with a way to parse it. Rather, you should fix the *root* of this issue, and just use one of the many existing serialization formats to persist your data.

Comment: ast is not defined

Comment: You need to `import ast`

Comment: getting a blank output

Comment: @Mahir can you please specify what exactly "x" are in your text file , it is digit or character or what ? or its exact same format as you given ?

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul well the first array is str(integer) so digits but in string format, and the rest are string like pharses/characters

Comment: @Mahir post an sample example with question.

Comment: https://ibb.co/cMOy0b 

right so basically, i want to remove the ( and [ and ) ] in the text file, so its like x,x,x,x,x
x being a value in that text file @AyodhyankitPaul

Comment: @Mahir try my updated solution.

Comment: @Mahir i have updated my solution basis on your screenshot , try it !

Answer (score 0):

will it help ? Try out :

```
list2=r"([x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,x],[x,x,x,x],[x,x,x])"

old_list=[i for i in list2]

new_list=[i for i in old_list if i!=',' and i!='(' and i!=')' and i!='[' and i!=']']

print(new_list)
```

output:

```
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
```

> Update soltion basis on your screenshot :

```
list_22=([1,2,3,4],["couple A","couple B","couple C"],["f","g","h"])

print([j for i in list_22 for j in i])
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'couple A', 'couple B', 'couple C', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

Comment: same issue/output maybe i can change the way i wrote the data to the file?

Comment: @Mahir i have updated my solution basis on your screenshot , try it !

Comment: why you are not posting exact input and error list what you are getting so i can see how you are passing list and how you are applying my solution ? don't post screenshot , use the pastebin to post output or sampledata.

Comment: because i need to extract the data from the text file and format it  thats the whole point. i dont need to make a new array with information.

Comment: post the output in pastebin.

Comment: if you are getting that output then this solution should work :
https://dpaste.de/xZbJ

Answer (score -1):

You can flatten the lists inside the tuple by looping over them like this.

```
tuple_of_lists = ([x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,,x],[x,x,x,x],[x,x,x])
resulting_list = []
for lis in tuple_of_lists:
    resulting_list.extend(lis)
```

I hope it helps.

Edited:-
May be this function can help.

```
def formatter(string):
    l = len(string)
    to_avoid = {',', '[', ']', '(', ')', '"'}
    lis = []
    temp = ''
    for i in range(l):
        if string[i] in to_avoid:
            if temp != '':
                lis.append(temp)
            temp = ''
            continue
        else:
            temp += string[i]
    return lis
```

Comment: how would i do that if its in a text file [the tuple of lists] sorry im new to python